# Trying to connect to remote db with python, error user denied from IP, however Workbench from my IP works just fine

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Im working on creating a python file meant to update tables in a database from a csv. The machine and the IP I am working from have access to the remote DB I am trying to connect to, but I keep recieving
Error while connecting to MySQL: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Important to note I am not the owner of this DB as such I cannot easily change permissions.

The python file is the only thing unable to connect, as MySQL Workbench is connecting and able to modify the DB just fine.